# JsonObject parsing without keys

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing, key-value

Iam trying to parse a json content to my android app. Iam using firebase db to get the results.

**What I have**

```
private void StartParse() {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                webserviceUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("Repsonse", response.toString());

            try {
                // Parsing json object response
                // response will be a json object

                String cover = response.optString("cover").toString();
                String ip_address = response.optString("ip_address").toString();
                String port = response.optString("port").toString();
                String info = response.optString("info").toString();
                String uid = response.optString("uid").toString();

                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(cover, cover.toString());
                // and so on..
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("Response", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // hide the progress dialog
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);

}
```

**What I need**
is that I have this json response here:

```
{  
"-KFOmfn3XcmM3BsrWYcZ":{  
  "company":"A17",
  "country":"France",
  "email":"test12@gmail.com",
  "uid":"720363f7-84f1-4a35-9551-9422da991835"
},
"-KTCLolTzHO0KFcuQR3B":{  
  "company":"B13",
  "country":"Sweden",
  "email":"test14@gmail.com",
  "uid":"7eade882-c182-441e-8793-94c6a1879a52"
},
"-KFcuQR3B1KTCLsa43BK10":{  
  "company":"C23",
  "country":"Denmark",
  "email":"France",
  "uid":"7eade882-c182-441e-8793-94c6a1879a52"
},
"-CLHOcuQoKFzRTl3BKx0T":{  
  "company":"4SS",
  "country":"Italy",
  "email":"test1@gmail.com",
  "uid":"7eade882-c182-441e-8793-94c6a1879a52"
}
}
```

the response is json file but how can I just grab the values? so I can have an array with the values only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String key = iter.next();
    try {
        Object value = json.get(key);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // Something went wrong!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Json Array so you have parse one by one object key. Something like this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
String company = jsonObject.getJSONObject("-KFOmfn3XcmM3BsrWYcZ").getString("company");
String country= jsonObject.getJSONObject("-KFOmfn3XcmM3BsrWYcZ").getString("country");
// email and uid same
String company1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("-KTCLolTzHO0KFcuQR3B").getString("company");
String country1= jsonObject.getJSONObject("-KTCLolTzHO0KFcuQR3B").getString("country");

......
```

Comment: the problem is I dont know the : getJSONObject("-KFOmfn3XcmM3BsrWYcZ") its dynamic and I cant control it.

Answer (score 0):

JsonObject parsing without keys in **Kotlin**. Please try this solution

```
     val jsonObjects = JSONObject(response.body().toString())
     val keys: Iterator<*> = jsonObjects.keys()
     while (keys.hasNext()) {
     val key = keys.next() as String
    if (jsonObjects.get(key) is JSONObject) {
       var jsonObject = jsonObjects.get(key)
    Log.d("jsonobject", jsonObject.toString())
    }
   }
```